# What signal is emitted when a QListWidgetItem has its data written immediately after it is inserted into a QListWidget?

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5

Right now I'm using the rowsInserted signal to print the first item in a list that is receiving drag and drops. The issue is when I drop an item into this list when it is empty, it prints "Updating, first item has text:" because the item was added to the list widget, but its data wasn't filled in yet. How do I tie into a signal that is emitted AFTER the new item has its data?

Here's the class I got right now. I have some other related code, but I figured this is sufficient.

```
class ReceiveDropList(QListWidget):
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(ReceiveDropList, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.setAcceptDrops(True)
    self.setDragDropMode(QAbstractItemView.DragDrop)
    self.model().rowsInserted.connect(lambda: print("Updating, first item has text:",self.item(0).text()))
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the QModelIndex of the rowsInserted signal to know the inserted texts:

```py
class ReceiveDropList(QListWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ReceiveDropList, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.setAcceptDrops(True)
        self.setDragDropMode(QAbstractItemView.DragDrop)
        self.model().rowsInserted.connect(self.handle_rows_inserted)

    def handle_rows_inserted(self, parent, first, last):
        for row in range(first, last + 1):
            index = self.model().index(row, 0, parent)
            print(index.data())
            # item = self.itemFromIndex(index)
            # if item is not None:
            #    print(item.text())
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! I ran your code including uncommenting the last 3 lines, however it still claims that the inserted item has text "" when I know for certain the text of the item I drag and dropped in has text "TEST" Would you like me to share the full program that reproduces this? It's only 43 lines.